# Why do IE kills cookie after closing it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cookies

I set a cookie using jQuery:

```
$.cookie('COOK', resp.cookieValue, {
        expires: 10000,
        path : '/', 
        domain : '.mydomain.com'});
```

After it I close the browser and open it again trying to get saved cookie. The result is the following:

```
var myCookie = $.cookie('COOK'); //myCookie is null
```

In Chrome this code works perfectly and cookie exists after reopen of browser, but not in IE. I looked over all settings in browser, but don't found any checked options of deleting temporary files.

Comment: You've set this cookie to expire `10` seconds after the unix epoch

Comment: @PaulS, if this is using `https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie` then the expiry is measured in days. OP, you might want to try lowering the figure to something like 365 and see if that makes a difference. IE might not be able to that figure.

Comment: @Andy, yeah, I tried to set low value of expires, but I didn't see a difference after changing

Comment: @PaulS. I use https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#expires and  as noted by Andy above the expiry is measured in days.

Comment: You might want to log this as an issue on the github page and see what the author says.

Comment: You may want to check your IE settings.  I think there is an option that you can set that will let IE delete cookies when you close the browser.  I don't think this is how it works by default.  I'd try resetting IE back to default settings and then test the cookie.